# How to print (in the screen) all JS code required by an iframe with external url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I want to show in an iframe a webpage (an external url), and then show all the code JS requested by this iframe in a textarea.

It's like a firebug console (where we can see all the scripts and theirs sources), but I can only use frontend language (can be any library, or even pure javascript).

I have a cross domain problem, and even when I am able to do the request (like using getScript) I am not able to get the source, the code itself... There is no "textResponse"...

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, but will require the use of a server to request the html and aggregate the information you need for your page. The browser won't be able to obtain that information for you due to the CORS policy

Comment: I was affraid of this :(

Comment: note that it doesn't have to be *your* server. look up YQL. With YQL you should be able to get a list of all <script> tags that contain a src attribute, but you won't be able to see any dynamically requested scripts.

Comment: @KevinB THANKS a lot, really, you have saved my day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get this information, however, it will require the use of a server.

However, it doesn't have to be *your* server, you can use a 3rd party server to get this information. One such service is YQL.

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+script+from+html+where+url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Ftrello.com'+AND+script.src+!%3D+''